# Confusing Sequence-Notation

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

I recently encountered the following definition:

> - *there exists a sequence of polynomials* $(p_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ *of fixed
>     degree* $\sigma$ *such that for every* $x\in U$,
>     $\left|f(n+x) - p_n(n+x) \right| \longrightarrow 0
>   \quad \text{as} \;n\to+\infty$

**What would one of these polynomials look like?**

---

I have seen polynomial sequences of the form $p_n(n^2)$, which would expand as $1, 4, 9...$ as well as polynomials of the form $p_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_nx^k$
In these cases $n$ was always the degree of the polynomial, though here we have polynomials of a fixed degree *as well as* polynomials in terms of $n+x$ as opposed to just $x$

I would assume that the polynomials in question would be in one of the following forms:

$$\begin{align} 
&1)\qquad p_n(n+x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\sigma}a_{n+x}(n+x)^k\\
&2)\qquad p_n(n+x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\sigma}a_{n+x}(n)^k\\
&3)\qquad p_n(n+x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\sigma}a_{n}(n+x)^k
\end{align}
$$

However, I am not quite sure which (if any) of these forms I should be looking at, which is hurting my understanding of the topic in general

The [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0502109.pdf) from which this comes claims that the natural logarithm can be approximated in this fashion by a sequence of degree $0$ using the above definition, and I am trying to find such a sequence. IF anyone could provide an explicit example that would be great as well!

*As noted in the comments, the paper in question (as well as additional constraints on $f$ which maps $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$) can be found in the linked question, though I do include such constraints here as I find them unnecessary to my specific question*

Comment: Are there conditions on f?

Comment: @qbert The full text definition reads as such: *Let* $U\subset \mathbb{C}$ *and* $\sigma\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{-\infty\}$.
*A function* $f\colon U\to\mathbb{C}$ *will be called a* (right) approximate 
polynomial of
degree $\sigma$ *if the following conditions are satisfied:*    

1) - all $u\in U$ satisfy $u+1\in U$  

2)  - *there exists a sequence of polynomials* $(p_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ *of fixed
degree* $\sigma$ *such that for every* $x\in U$,
$\left|f(n+x) - p_n(n+x) \right| \longrightarrow 0
\quad \text{as} \;n\to+\infty$

Comment: so as far as I can tell the only restrictions on $f$ are that it takes a complex number and outputs a complex number. Specifically the author mentions $\log x$ and $\sqrt{x}$, though generalizations later in the paper are made for all $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$

Comment: @qbert the context can be found in the post I linked if needed, as can the paper in question.

Answer (score 2):

The paper says that only the behavior of $f(x)$ as $\text{Re}\,x\to\infty$ matters. In the example $f(x)=\log x$ the authors are taking $U=(0,\infty)$. Consider $p_n=\log n$. Then for every $x>0$,
$$\log(x+n)-\log n=\log \frac{x+n}{n}=\log\left( 1+\frac{x}{n}\right)\to 0$$
as $n\to\infty$. Similarly for $f(x)=\sqrt x$ consider $p_n=\sqrt n$. Then for every $x>0$,
$$\sqrt{x+n}-\sqrt n=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+n}+\sqrt n}\to 0$$
as $n\to\infty$.
So I guess that in general you look at the speed at which $f$ is going to infinity, namely you consider the limit
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x+iy)}{x^\sigma}=\ell$$
and if this limit exists and it is finite for some nonnegative integer $\sigma$ (uniformly in $y$?), then you will use polynomials of degree $\sigma$. If $\ell\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, a first try would be $p_n(x)=\ell x^\sigma+a_{n-1,\sigma} x^{\sigma-1}+\ldots$.

Your polynomials will be of the form (3) since (1) and (2) are not polynomials (the coefficients cannot depend on $x$).

Not all functions can be approximated like that. For example for $f(x)=e^x$ I don't think you can construct such a sequence. So the authors are considering functions that as  $\text{Re}\,x\to\infty$ behave like a polynomial. That's why they called these functions approximate polynomial.